# Filter documents based on array size inside a root array element Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[image]

Hello, I'd like to get all the documents where `categories` array has an element with key `CONSULTANT_AGREEMENT` and the respective `subCategories` array inside the `CONSULTANT_AGREEMENT` category contains only one element.

Is this possible in MongoDB or should I write a service function on top of the result set?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done without unwinding, and by further limiting the amount of returned documents to perform aggregation on by filtering by both the categories.name and the size of the subCategories array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "categories": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "key": "CONSULTANT_AGREEMENT",
          "subCategories": {
            $size: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "eg": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$categories",
          as: "category",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$$category.subCategories"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yl33-Y54imX) for a live example.

You can also add any additional fields that you want to the projection stage of the pipeline.

Comment: Check out [this case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HB4V1eGMLsZ)

Comment: Like @nimrodserok pointed out, my previous solution was wrong so I've updated it.
However, Tom Slabbert has since provided a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!, I would personally [elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as this allows you to use the `find` cursor options and avoid the aggregation pipeline overhead.

like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  categories: {
    $elemMatch: {
      key: "CONSULTANT_AGREEMENT",
      $and: [
        {
          "subCategories.0": {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          "subCategories.1": {
            $exists: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yoavtt4LnNd)

Comment: But this will also return documents with `subCategories` size of more than 1

Comment: I did not see he required only 1 element exactly, it can easily be changed, just wraped it with an `$and` condition. still the idea is to avoid the aggregation pipeline when possible

Comment: Nicely done! voted for it